# Migrating from PostgreSQL to MySQL (data with \r\n)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, pg-dump

I'm trying to migrate a database from PostgreSQL to MySQL on an Ubuntu 23.04 system (latest version of both).

So far, it looks like things are fine, except for one problem.  In one of the character varying fields in PostgreSQL, there are `\r\n` characters.  Yeah -- whoever developed this system made a front-end that allowed them.

I'm saving the data using a command such as this:

`pg_dump -U mylogin --data-only --file=foo.sql --no-owner --column-inserts --table foo --quote-all-identifiers`

which:

- does not output the schema (I have separate `CREATE TABLE` statements for that)
- creates only `INSERT` statements
- does not associate an owner to the table

`--quote-all-identifiers` was something I tried and it seems having it or not having it does not solve my problem.  My problem is that I might have a row like:

```
[1, "hello", "hello\r\nthere"]
```

which looks like this in `foo.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (id, comment1, comment2) VALUES (1, 'hello', 'hello
there');
```

and MySQL does not like this (i.e. `mysql -u mylogin -p <foo.sql`.  When doing backups and restorations within PostgreSQL, there wasn't any problem since `pg_dump` with default options uses `COPY`.

I looked through the options for `pg_dump` and no obvious option jumps up at me that would solve this problem.  I thought having a quote would (i.e., `--quote-all-identifiers`), but it did not.

I'm not sure if I should look into how PostgreSQL is exporting it or how MySQL is importing it...or some other solution I haven't yet thought of.

I was thinking of doing this on the PostgreSQL database:

`update TEST set comment2 = regexp_replace (description, E'([\\n\\r]+)', ' ', 'g');`

(Untested)  But I guess I would rather not change the source data if I can.

Does anyone have a suggestion about what I should do?  Or perhaps I'm going about this wrong...  Thank you!

Comment: You can use [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) to postgres and use statement like this: `insert into fdw_table_schema.my_table .. select .. from my_table_schema._mytable`

Comment: @SahapAsci Thanks for the comment and sorry for my late reply.  The link is useful, but it'll take me some time to digest it.  I will look into it as my current solution (so far) is to do the `update TEST set comment2 ...` to change the original database.

Answer (score 0):

I has similar issue a while ago. Here are my steps that succeed:

- export table from PostgreSQL

```
    pg_dump -U postgres -W -d pgs_db_name -t pgs_table_name --column-inserts > /path/to/dumpfile.sql
```

- in the resulting file replace double quotes around database object names by backticks and import into MySQL

```
    mysql -u root -p mysql_db_name -vvf < /path/to/dumpfile.sql
```

However, doing this for multiple tables took some time, therefore I decided to move further with [this converter](https://www.convert-in.com/pgs2sql.htm) that can handle '\r\n' properly.

Answer (score -1):

Loose the `--quote-all-identifiers`

After that you get something like:

```
INSERT INTO public.foo (t) VALUES ('this is a \r\ntest');
```

Get (somehow) rid of the `public.` and things should work

```
INSERT INTO foo (t) VALUES ('this is a \r\ntest');
```

EDIT:  I see that i am missing [What's the "E" before a Postgres string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823158/whats-the-e-before-a-postgres-string), to make the `\r\n` be handled as carriage return and newline character.

So, this works:

```
INSERT INTO foo (t) VALUES (E'this is a \r\ntest');
```

Comment: That won't work.

Comment: What, in `that`, won't work ?

Comment: Because if you `INSERT` that string, you will insert backslash and `n` rather than a newline. Consequently, `pg_dump` won't produce such an output. Did you try it? To escape newlines in a string literal, you have to write `E'two\nlines'`, but `pg_dump` doesn't do that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for your comment!  Indeed, that doesn't work.  In fact, in my original question, I said "seems having it or not having it does not solve my problem".  That is, I had tried with or without it before I posted my original question.  Maybe it could work with something else which I do not know about -- but just removing the option does not work.